# Pyspark Timestamp to Date conversion using when condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I have source table A with startdatecolumn as timestamp it has rows with invalid date such as 0000-01-01. while inserting into table B I want it to be in Date datatype and I want to replace 0000-01-01 with 1900-01-01.
My code:

```
df= tableA.withColumn(
    'StartDate',
    to_date(when(col('StartDate') == '0001-01-01', '1900-01-01').otherwise(col('StartDate'))
    )
)
```

I am getting 0000-12-31 date instead of 1900-01-01

how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `0001-01-01` instead of `0000-01-01`

Try with:

```
df= tableA.withColumn(
    'StartDate',
    to_date(when(col('StartDate') == '0000-01-01', '1900-01-01').otherwise(col('StartDate'))
    )
```

Comment: I am getting same output.

Comment: could you add sample input data to test?